# Proportion in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
  Location  Type  Number
     House    A      4
              B      1
     Garden   A      3
              B      2
```

I am trying to find a way to create a column of proportion of type B in each location.

Expected output -

```
Location  Type  Number Proportion_B
 House    A      4        20%
          B      1        20%  
 Garden   A      3        40%
          B      2        40%
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: Locations are objects,  Type categories, Number ints

Comment: OK, what is `print (df.index)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#create MultiIndex
df1 = df.set_index(['Location','Type'])
#if necessary aggregate sum per both levels
#df1 = df1.sum(level=[0,1])

#select B level and divide by sum
df2 = df1.xs('B', level=1).div(df1.sum(level=0), level=1).mul(100).add_prefix('prop_B_')
print (df2)
          prop_B_Number
Location               
House              20.0
Garden             40.0

#join to original DataFrame
df = df.join(df2, on='Location')
print (df)
  Location Type  Number  prop_B_Number
0    House    A       4           20.0
1    House    B       1           20.0
2   Garden    A       3           40.0
3   Garden    B       2           40.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way,

```
temp= df.groupby('Location').apply(lambda x: ((x[x['Type']=='B']['Number']/x['Number'].sum())*100)).reset_index().rename(columns={'Number':'Proportion_B'})
temp=temp[['Location','Proportion_B']]
temp['Proportion_B']=temp['Proportion_B'].astype(str).str.replace('\.0','')+'%'
df=pd.merge(df,temp,how='left',on=['Location'])
```

Output:

```
  Location Type  Number Proportion_B
0    House    A       4          20%
1    House    B       1          20%
2   Garden    A       3          40%
3   Garden    B       2          40%
```

Explanation:

1. Group the elements by `Location`, then divide the total number with only B and save this result.
2. Merge the temp result with original df based on `Location' using`left` merge.

**Note:**
 Line 2, Line 3 for getting the same sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this on

```
df_temp = df.groupby('Location').apply(lambda x: ((x[x['Type']=='B']['Number']/x['Number'].sum())*100)).reset_index().rename(columns={'Number':'Proportion_B'})
df=pd.merge(df,df_temp,how='left',on=['Location'])
```